# factoring a trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry, factoring

The graph of $2\cos(y)-\cos(3x)-\cos(x)=0$ (here's [a link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427em3rchel2lf)) suggests to me that this expression can be factored on the left, but I haven't uncovered how. Any trig masters out there who can see the factors? Or can give an explanation as to why such a factorization is impossible?

Comment: Can we use $$\cos2C+\cos2D=2\cos(C-D)\cos(C+D)?$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the entire left can be factored, since it has the separate $\cos y$ term. However if one moves things over the equation becomes
$$2\cos y=\cos(3x)+\cos(x)=-2\cos(x)\cdot(2\sin^2 x-1),$$
so that for example one could maybe pick out the $x$ values going with the $y$ for which $\cos y=0,$ if that's any help.